# Safari not picking up index.php

Tags: php, safari

My site is php driven, apart from a few pages. I wanted the index to run in php as there is at least one element at the moment that utilises the database. All other browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Edge on Mac & Windows) use the index.php apart from Safari which seems to only want to pick up the .htm. I have a very simple .htaccess doc:

#The DirectoryIndex is index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php index.htm index.html

Which I thought would be enough.
I don't seem to have access to the Apache folder or the httpd.conf file to use that to add an index.
So I'm wondering what is happening, why would Safari not use the same as the other browsers.

Comment: It's not up to the browser, so you're either directly accessing the `.htm` version by having the filename in the URL, or you're seeing a cached result. (You might consider just removing the `index.htm` entirely if you're not using it.)

Comment: Already cleared the cache several times for all browsers on two PCs and a Mac, made no difference to Safari, still used the .htm not .php. I also got rid of the index.htm as well, in that instance Safari returned a 404 error, so I put the .htm back.

Comment: What I have noticed is the URL that Safari initially tries to open is http://xxxxxxx.xxx/index.htm (even when it has been deleted). I I delete the .htm ref then hit enter Safari opens the .php file. When I open a new tab and rerun Safari it again picks the .htm file. Maybe its a Safari thing? Always requesting .htm rather than using .php.

Comment: Pretty sure that's just Safari suggesting possible auto-completions from your browsing history. Try clearing your history.

Comment: You are absolutely right ceejayoz now I feel totally stupid!